# How can I call an event hanlder inside another event handler that have different params in asp?

Tags: c#, asp.net

The two event handler that I try with, I want to call the RowDataBound event haner inside the SelectedIndexChanged event handler.

1. RowDataBound
2. SelectedIndexChanged

Comment: Why? This make no sense to me!

Comment: Please post your code, otherwise its hard to help, you may be able to do something like `SomeEvent(null, null);` but it's hard to say without seeing the code.